# C# pass password via StandardInput of Process

Tags: c#, process, passwords, stdin

The next C# method invokes `rasdial VPN-Name name *`. `*` means *enter password* from keyboard. But I want to pass the password to the process from C# application.

```
  public bool connect(UserCredentials userCredentials)
  {
    // "Dial" to VPN
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("rasdial")//("cmd")
    {
      RedirectStandardInput = true,
      RedirectStandardOutput = true,
      RedirectStandardError = true,
      //CreateNoWindow = true,
      UseShellExecute = false,  // Unusable if Streams redirected
      Arguments = $"{InterfaceName} {userCredentials.name} *"
    };

    var proc = new Process {
      StartInfo = psi
      //,EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };
    proc.Start();

    // PASS PASSWORD VIA STDIN. Does not work. Keyboard input FORCED!
    //proc.WaitForInputIdle();
    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(userCredentials.pass);

    proc.WaitForExit();

    return true;// proc.ExitCode == 0;  // Can throws "Not exited yet"
  }
```

**Is there a way to pass the password to `rasdial`?**

I can invoke `rasdial VPN-Name login passwd`. **Such method is security lack. DEPRECATED**. *Any schoolboy can monitor process's args.*

Answer (score 0):

#### One workaround

```
static Process runProcRasdial()
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd") {
        RedirectStandardInput=true,
        RedirectStandardOutput=false,
        UseShellExecute=false
    };
    var proc = new Process(){
        StartInfo = psi,
        EnableRaisingEvents = true,
    };
    proc.Start();
    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("rasdial rapa /disconnect");
    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("rasdial rapa Ivan paswd!");
    //proc.Exited += Proc_Exited1;
    proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
    proc.WaitForExit();
    return proc;
}
```

If pack *paswd!* to `SecureString` if could look like something normal.